# RestClientException doesnot Rollback entire transaction

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

Please refer to the below snippet of code

```java
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = { Throwable.class })
@Override
public MyClass myMethod(myParams) {
  try{
    myRepo.saveAll(myEntityList);

    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(myUrl,requestParam,String.class);
    if(responseEnity.getBody()!=null && StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(responseEnity.getBody(),"Failure")){
      log.error("Rest Call Failed");
      throw new RestClientException("Error in remote service");
   }
  }catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Now in the console log, I can see `RestClientException` being thrown but `myRepo.saveAll(myEntityList);` doesn't rollback instead it is inserting data into DB.

Can anyone figure out the issue?

My requirement is that in `RestServiceCall` if I get a failure response then my current transaction should get rollback entirely.

Comment: How `myMethod()` method is called and which class does that?

Comment: It will not rollback , the exception is being caught

Comment: myMethod() is being called from controller layer and this method resides in service layer.
In dao layer/repo layer i donot have any separate transaction.All the transactions are maintained by service layer only

Comment: @ meobeo173 my understanding is that from inside try block if any exception is occurred spring is supposed to rollback all dml operations occurring within that try block.

Comment: @meobeo173 is right, you need to either remove the try-catch or catch the exception, log something and rethrow another exception.

Comment: @meobao173 yes got it

Comment: @meobeo173 add your comment as an answer so that it can be accepted and the question closed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transaction is not rollbacked because there is no exception thrown, you're catching it.

As @Sumit Ghost mentioned, you can log it and rethrow the exception